# How do I handle the call back using multiple Google File Picker

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

If I have multiple Google Drive File Pickers on one page how do I handle the callback to ensure the data is passed to the correct section?

I basically have a number of items listed, each Item has a select a file button linked to the file picker. All the examples just pass the data back to the same place but I need this to be different for each request.

I'm basically have the same code that is included in the docs:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs#file-open_dialogs

How can I do this?﻿

[image: multiple file pickers]

Answer (score 1):

As Eric said use the setCallback method.

If you want to pass a parameter to a callback use an anonymous function:

.setCallback(function(data){pickerCallback(data,"MYPICKERID")})

Comment: If I pass through an anonymous function I get the error "undefined is not a function" this is when having picker.setCallback(function(return){pickerCallback(return, formId)}) I get an error. If I just have picker.setCallback(pickerCallback) the picker works.

Comment: Hey my bad I changed my variable of "ret" to "return" to make it more readable for the post.  "return" is a reserved word. Change return to something else and make sure your callback function matches the call ie
    function pickerCallback(data, pickerID){ do stuff... }

Answer (score 0):

You can change the callback function that the picker uses with this line:

```
.setCallback(pickerCallback)
```

Use a different callback for each picker, or even use an anonymous function.

Comment: Hey Eric, would it be possible to pass through an ID to the .setCallBack? All items are created dynamically so a separate function for each wouldn't really work. Would something like .setCallBack(pickerCallback(itemId)) work?