# Reusable Google doc Picker in google scripts - Picker Callback

Tags: google-apps-script, google-picker

**Docu References**:

1. [Drive file picker v3](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/picker)
2. G Suite Dialogs: [File Open Dialog](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs#file-open_dialogs)

**SO References**:

1. [Access data in Google App Script from spread sheet modal html form](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49444406/6215377)
2. [How do I handle the call back using multiple Google File Picker](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25645715/6215377)

**What to achieve?**

In a *Google Sheets script*, I would like to define a Files Picker that returns the `data` of picked up files, provided that thereon, from another part of the scripts, the caller can receive that `data`.

**Problem:**

The file picker is launched as an `html` *Modal* dialog. After searching for a while, the **only solution to get the `data` from the script** that launched the `picker` is from the `html` script code:

1. set the `callaback` of the picker to a specific function: `picker.setCallback(my_callback)`
2. or use `google.script.run.my_callback` (i.e. from button `Done` for instance)

... provided that `my_callback` function defined in your script gets the `data`.

The problem with the above is that you cannot use the same `picker` for multiple purposes, because:

1. `my_callback` is **fixed** in the `html` script
2. `my_callback` cannot know for what purpose the `picker` was initially called (i.e. *should it get the content?*, *should it give the information to some unknown caller?*).

Once it gets the `data`, `my_callback` does not know what to do with it... unless `my_callback` is tied to only 1 caller; which does not seem correct, as that would require to have multiple `html` definitions for the `picker`, once per each reason you may invoke it, so it can call back to the proper function.

**Any ideas?**

- global variables in scripts get re-initialized and cannot use [PropertiesService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties-service) to store values other than `String` (so no way to store the final `picker_callback` through a global var).
- `google.script.run` does not offer calls by giving the name of the server-side function as `String` ([reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run)) (which discards having a function to generate the `picker_dialog.html` by changing the callback function).

**Sample Code**

`code.gs`

```js
function ui() {
  return SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
}

function onOpen() {
  ui().createMenu('ecoPortal Tools')
      .addItem('Read a file', 'itemReadFile')
      .addItem('Edit a file', 'itemEditFile')
      .addToUi();
}

function itemReadFile() {
  pickFile(readFile)
}

function itemEditFile() {
  pickFile(editFile)
}

function readFile(data) {
  /* do some stuff */
}

function editFile(data) {
  /* do some stuff */
}
```

`picker.gs`:

```js
function pickFile(callback) {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('picker_dialog.html')
      .setWidth(600)
      .setHeight(425)
      .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);

  // concept (discarded):
  callback_set('picker', callback)
  ui().showModalDialog(html, 'Select a file');
}

function getOAuthToken() {
  DriveApp.getRootFolder();
  return ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
}

// picker callback hub
function pickerCallback(data) {
  var callback = callback_get('picker');
  callback_set('picker', null);
  if (callback) callback.call(data);
}
```

`picker_dialog.html`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons.css">
  <script>
    var DEVELOPER_KEY = '___PICKER_API_KEY_____';
    var DIALOG_DIMENSIONS = {width: 600, height: 425};
    var pickerApiLoaded = false;
    // currently selected files data
    var files_data = null;

    /**
     * Loads the Google Picker API.
     */
    function onApiLoad() {
      gapi.load('picker', {'callback': function() {
        pickerApiLoaded = true;
      }});
     }

    function getOAuthToken() {
      console.log("going to call get auth token :)");
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(createPicker)
          .withFailureHandler(showError).getOAuthToken();
    }

    function createPicker(token) {
      console.log("pickerApiLoadded", pickerApiLoaded);
      console.log("token", token);

      if (pickerApiLoaded && token) {
        var picker = new google.picker.PickerBuilder()
            .addView(google.picker.ViewId.DOCS)
            .enableFeature(google.picker.Feature.NAV_HIDDEN)
            .hideTitleBar()
            .setOAuthToken(token)
            .setDeveloperKey(DEVELOPER_KEY)
            .setCallback(pickerCallback)
            .setOrigin(google.script.host.origin)
            .setSize(DIALOG_DIMENSIONS.width - 2,
                DIALOG_DIMENSIONS.height - 2)
            .build();
        picker.setVisible(true);
      } else {
        showError('Unable to load the file picker.');
      }
    }

    function pickerCallback(data) {
      var action = data[google.picker.Response.ACTION];

      if (action == google.picker.Action.PICKED) {
        files_data = data;
        var doc = data[google.picker.Response.DOCUMENTS][0];
        var id = doc[google.picker.Document.ID];
        var url = doc[google.picker.Document.URL];
        var title = doc[google.picker.Document.NAME];
        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML =
            '<b>You chose:</b><br>Name: <a href="' + url + '">' + title +
            '</a><br>ID: ' + id;

      } else if (action == google.picker.Action.CANCEL) {
        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = 'Picker canceled.';
      }
    }

    function showError(message) {
      document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = 'Error: ' + message;
    }

    function closeIt() {
      google.script.host.close();
    }

    function returnSelectedFilesData() {
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(closeIt).pickerCallback(files_data);
    }

  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div>
    <button onclick='getOAuthToken()'>Select a file</button>
    <p id='result'></p>
    <button onclick='returnSelectedFilesData()'>Done</button>
  </div>
  <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js?onload=onApiLoad"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25652350/)? What do you mean by multiple purpose? Some of your assumptions are wrong. But it's unclear what you want to do.

Comment: let's say i want to use the picker to do different stuff with the files obtained: (a) pick up file to load some content, (b) pick up a file to read some definitions and use them from the app, (c) pick up a file to write some results, (d) pick up a file to import some tabs. Using the example you mention, the `callback` in each case would be different, wouldn't it?

Comment: Still not sure what you want, but I'll add a answer.

Comment: Could you give a full overview? Or flow?  Something like: User wants to get metadata of a file>user clicks menu >  main function> main function opens picker> user selects a file from  his drive in the picker> file is sent from html to gs/server=> server reads metadata of file and returns it to html>html shows the returned data from server=> success

Comment: @TheMaster I think the core problem is that I did not see the framework's client-server duality. I was thinking in creating a continuous workflow between server-client parts, notwithstanding that there were actually separated client and server sides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> picker.setCallback(my_callback)

Picker callback is different from:

> or use google.script.run.my_callback

The former calls a function on the frontend html while the latter calls a function in the server.

> my_callback cannot know for what purpose the picker was initially called

You can send a argument to the server:

```
google.script.run.my_callback("readFile");
```

On the server side(`code.gs`),

```
fuction my_callback(command){
  if(command === "readFile") Logger.log("Picker called me to readFile");
}
```

> google.script.run does not offer calls by giving the name of the server-side function as String

Not true. Dot is used to access members of a object. You can use bracket notation to access a member as a string:

```
google.script.run["my_callback"]();
```

---

**EDITED BY Q.ASKER:**

In your case, to pass the `files_data` to the server side:

```
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(closeIt)[my_callback](files_data);
```

Now, for `my_callback` (String variable) to be set from server side, you need to push it using [templates](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates#pushing_variables_to_templates):

```
function pickFile(str_callback) {
  var htmlTpl = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('picker_dialog.html');
  // push variables
  htmlTpl.str_callback = str_callback;

  var htmlOut = htmlTpl.evaluate()
      .setWidth(600)
      .setHeight(425)
      .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);

  ui().showModalDialog(htmlOut, 'Select a file');
}
```

The two unique changes that you need to make to your `picker_dialog.html`:

1. add [printing scriptlet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates#printing_scriptlets) to set `my_callback` (`<?= ... ?>`)
2. use the `google.script.run` as mentioned

```js
var my_callback       = <?= str_callback? str_callback : 'defaultPickerCallbackToServer' ?>;

/* ... omitted code ... */

function returnSelectedFilesData() {
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(closeDialog)[my_callback](files_data);
}
```

Now, when you call `pickFile` to open the frontend picker, you are able to set a different server `callback` that will receive the `data` with the file(s) chosen by the user.

Comment: you last line made the difference.... thank you :) so just need to generate the `picker_dialog.html` by changing the callback and that must do it... will try and come back

Comment: @rellampec Are you looking for [templated html](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates)?

Comment: I had a look... hmm, that may be the only option, l guess? The idea is that `pickFile` function uses parameter `callback` to generate `picker_dialog.html`, so `returnSelectedFilesData` function in the frontend uses `google.script.run["string_callback"]()` and closes correctly the cycle of picking up the file by calling the proper function on server side.

Comment: I will try your suggestion with [templates](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates), as it looks really clean. I see that a front end script `var` can be used to pass data from the server :)

Comment: I got  it working using your suggestion of using [templates](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates#pushing_variables_to_templates); pushed `str_callback` in `pickFile` and used it in the `picker_dialog.html`, `returnSelectedFilesData` function, like this: `google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(closeIt)[str_callback](files_data);` . This allows to use `pickFile` on server side to any purpose by just giving the callback string as parameter: `pickFile("getContent")`, `pickFile("addToSelected")`, `pickFile("appendText")`